# Frankfurt stock exchange companies

Tags: equities

I can't seem to find all the symbols for companies traded at Frankfurt stock exchange, presented as csv (or any downloadable format). Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://www.deutsche-boerse-cash-market.com/dbcm-en/instruments-statistics/statistics/listes-companies for an Excel. It is however an Excel, with each sector on a different tab

Comment: https://www.deutsche-boerse-cash-market.com/dbcm-en/primary-market/market-structure/segments describes the three segments (or sectors) of the market (i.e. the three tabs in the Excel sheet). The biggest and most well known companies  are in the first or Prime segment.